# How Can I load _pb2.py file to FileDescriptorSet

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

How Can I read _pb2.py file to FileDescriptorSet. In C# I can do so.

```
var set = new FileDescriptorSet();

var r = File.OpenText($@"{args[0]}");
set.Add(defaultOutputName, true, r);

et.Process();
```

But how I can it in python? I am trying this code but it didn't work.

```
_DESCR_FILE = os.path.abspath("../../../examples/cluster_grain_hello_world/messages/protos_pb2.py")

    with open(_DESCR_FILE, 'rb') as f:
        file_descriptor_str = f.read()

        file_descriptor = descriptor_pb2.FileDescriptorSet()
        file_descriptor.ParseFromString(file_descriptor_str)
```

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to poll the file descriptor set for new data? Or are you trying to add files to a set of entities for a function to process? (Hint: Not everyone is polylingual and understands C#.)

Comment: I would like to get names of messages and services that defined in _pb2.py

Comment: All of the attributes and function names associated with an object (and module) are in the `__dict__` attribute. You need to import the protos_pb2 module, i.e., `import protos_pb2` and then you can interrogate the module object's dictionary, `protos_pb2.__dict__`